# Invoke-Command one to Many without timeouts

Tags: powershell, jobs, parallel.foreach, invoke-command

I am trying to run series of commands on remote Windows Servers.

Some of these servers are up and some of them not. To some I have access and to some of them I do not have access.

Options to address this:

I can go with:

```
$Computername = PC1, PC2, PC3 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -FilePath .\script
```

Now what bugs me is that the invoke-command timeout takes too long and cannot made shorter.

So what I was thinking about is to use PowerShell 7 Parallel loops + Invoke-Command + Powershell Jobs:

```
$server_list = Import-Csv .\server-list.csv
$list = $server_list.Name

$my_array = $list | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 32 -Parallel {

    $x = start-job -name $_ -ScriptBlock { invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -FilePath .\script.ps1}
    $x | Wait-Job -Timeout 5
    $x | Where-Object {$_.State -ne "Completed"} | Stop-Job
    $zz = Receive-Job -Name $_
    $zz
}

$my_array
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Invoke-Command: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
Invoke-Command: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
Invoke-Command: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Any idea how to address this?

Comment: `-ComputerName $_` should be `-ComputerName $using:_` but also, if you have `-Parallel` means you also have `Start-ThreadJob` and also means there is no reason to use `Start-Job` which will make the whole script only slower

Comment: I see, can you give me please a working example so that I can play around with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can apply the logic you're looking for without so much overhead, you only really need a loop to enumerate each computer and [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.2) which comes pre-installed in PowerShell Core.

As for the error, you can use the [`$using:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.2#using-local-variables) when referring to variable defined in the local scope. [Example 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-9-include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer) from the docs has a good explanation on this.

```
$jobs = foreach($computer in (Import-Csv .\server-list.csv).Name) {
    Start-ThreadJob {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:computer -FilePath .\script.ps1
    } -ThrottleLimit 32
}

# Wait 5 seconds for them
$jobs | Wait-Job -Timeout 5
# Split the array between Completed and the other states // Running, Failed, etc.
$completed, $failed = $jobs.Where({ $_.State -eq 'Completed' }, 'Split')
# get the output from the completed ones
$completed | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

# These maybe you want to output to console before removing?
$failed | Stop-Job -PassThru | Remove-Job
```